# Can I create multi-paragraph footnotes in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer, footnote

For a writing project I need to be able to do slightly complex footnotes, with multiple paragraphs that are justified and images that are centered.

While typing the text of, say, footnote 13, pressing Enter seems to start a new paragraph but with a new number, 14. I don't want a new footnote, I want to continue the previous footnote.

Pressing Shift+Enter gives the rough appearance of a new paragraph (without inserting a new footnote number), but since the text is justified, the last line of text before the Shift+Enter gets stretched across the whole width of the footnote area, even if it's just a word or two. Then, if I insert an image (anchored as a character, alone in its "paragraph"), highlight it and try to apply centering, all the text in the footnote gets centered.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran across this partial solution: Options -> LibreOffice Writer -> Compatibility -> Expand word space on lines with manual line breaks in justified paragraphs (deselect). This stops stretching the text on the last line before the Shift+Enter (but doesn't solve the problem of centering the images).